# Ionic Framework using Angular 8 - Basic HTML form's required, min, max validation not working

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

This is my code

**emp.page.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="emiForm" (ngSubmit)="calculateEmi()">
        <!-- Loan Amount -->
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Loan Amount* </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" inputmode="numeric" clearInput="true" required min="1" max="999999999" formControlName="loanAmount"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <!-- Rate of Interest -->
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Interest Rate* </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" inputmode="numeric" clearInput="true" required="true" min="1" max="100" formControlName="interest"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <!-- No. of Year -->
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Loan Tenure* in Years </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" inputmode="numeric" clearInput="true" required="true" min="1" max="50" formControlName="tenure"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <ion-button type="submit" color="primary" expand="full">Calculate</ion-button>
      </form>
```

[image]

Why I submit a form, the basic required, min and max validations are not happening. It is triggering the calculateEmi() directly.

I tried calling the method from on button submit, not working.

Even If I removed `ngSubmit`, validations are not working.

Is there anything I am missing?

**emi.page.ts**

```
...
...
this.emiForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      loanAmount: ['', Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(999999999)],
      interest: ['', Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(100)],
      tenure: ['', Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(100)],
    });
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you to disable the submit button if the form isn't valid.

You could disable the submit button if the form is invalid, by using the [invalid](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#invalid) property on the `FormGroup`.

The `ion-button` has a `disabled` [input property](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#properties)

```html
<ion-button [disabled]="emiForm.invalid" type="submit" color="primary" expand="full">
  Calculate
</ion-button>
```

The [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#formgroup) has a few properties you can use.

**EDIT**

Check you console for errors, as its recommended to have validation in one place (not in your template and component).

Also, multiple validators need to be provided in an array:

```js
this.emiForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    loanAmount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(999999999)]],
    interest: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(100)]],
    tenure: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(100)]],
});
```

You also may want to consider adding in your own validation messages in the template rather than relying on the native browser errors.

Comment: I got it. It is not [disable], it is [disabled].

However, my question is why basic validation message is not thorwn?

Comment: you mean why its not shown* in the browser? Your screen shot is showing the native browser validation message.